# Sqrt in Assembly x86

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, x86, mismatch

I've found some suggestions online.

- [C Inline assembly - Operand type mismatch for 'fst'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736601/c-inline-assembly-operand-type-mismatch-for-fst)
- [Why am I getting these assembler errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392413/why-am-i-getting-these-assembler-errors)
- [Why will I have operand type mismatch error when compiling the assembly codes with gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041964/why-will-i-have-operand-type-mismatch-error-when-compiling-the-assembly-codes-wi)

I have a similar problem but none of the suggestions helped (or I did not figure out correctly how to implement them according to my program).

The code is inserted as `asm(...)` in a C program.

After compiling with `-masm=intel`, when using:

```
asm ("FLD EBX \n" "FSQRT \n" "FST EBX \n").
```

I get the compilation error:

"Error: operand type mismatch for 'fld'"
"... mismatch for 'fst'".

EBX holds some integer positive value before these commands.

So what is the correct way of getting ebx = sqrt(ebx)?

Comment: You can't load into the FPU from a general purpose register. You need to go through memory. See the instruction set reference. `push ebx; fild dword [esp]; fsqrt; fistp dword [esp]; pop ebx`. Note that there is usually no need for assembly, and that gcc inline assembly is a complicated beast.

Comment: Please make a [mcve] instead of a mere snippet.

Comment: @Jester hey I've seen this scheme in some site but didn't understand what should I insert instead of dword and esp?

Comment: `esp` is the stack pointer, you don't insert anything "instead of" it. `dword` might need to be `dword ptr`, that just indicates the size of the operand.

Comment: @Jester you're right about the esp .. I got confused for a second (I'm nee to assembly by the way)

Comment: But thanks I'll try that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use SSE / SSE2 for sqrt in modern code, not x87.  You can directly convert an integer in a gp register to a double in an xmm register with one instruction.

```
cvtsi2sd  xmm0, ebx
sqrtsd    xmm0, xmm0     ; sd means scalar double, as opposed to SIMD packed double
cvttsd2si  ebx, xmm0     ; convert with truncation (C-style cast)

; cvtsd2si  ecx, xmm0    ; rounded to nearest integer (or whatever the current rounding mode is)
```

This works for 64bit integers, too (`rbx`), but note that `double` can only exactly represent integers up to about 2^53 (mantissa size).  If you want to check if an integer is a perfect square, you can use float sqrt and then do a trial multiplication of the integer result.  (`(a*a) == b`)

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) for links to guides, tutorials, and manuals.

---

**Note that inserting this code into the middle of a C program is completely the wrong approach**.  GNU C inline asm is the hardest way to do asm, because you have to really understand everything to get the constraints right.  Getting them wrong can lead to other surrounding code breaking in subtle and hard-to-debug ways, rather than just the thing you're doing with inline asm being wrong.  See the x86 tag wiki for more detail about this.

If you want `int a = sqrt((int)b)`, then write that in your code and let the compiler generate those three instructions for you.  By all means read and understand the compiler output, but don't just blindly plop a sequence in the middle of it with `asm("")`.

e.g.:

```
#include <math.h>
int isqrt(int a) { return sqrt(a); }
```

[compiles to](http://goo.gl/7UJWA9) (gcc 5.3 without -ffast-math):

```
    pxor    xmm0, xmm0      # D.2569
    cvtsi2sd        xmm0, edi       # D.2569, a
    sqrtsd  xmm1, xmm0  # tmp92, D.2569
    ucomisd xmm1, xmm1        # tmp92, tmp92
    jp      .L7 #,
    cvttsd2si       eax, xmm1     # D.2570, tmp92
    ret
.L7:
    sub     rsp, 8    #,
    call    sqrt    #
    add     rsp, 8    #,
    cvttsd2si       eax, xmm0     # D.2570, tmp92
    ret
```

I guess `sqrt()` has to set errno on some kinds of errors. :/

With `-fno-math-errno`:

```
    pxor    xmm0, xmm0      # D.2569
    cvtsi2sd        xmm0, edi       # D.2569, a
    sqrtsd  xmm0, xmm0  # tmp92, D.2569
    cvttsd2si       eax, xmm0     # D.2570, tmp92
    ret
```

The `pxor` is to break the false dependency on the previous contents of xmm0, because `cvtsi2sd` made the strange design decision to leave the upper half of the dest vector reg unmodified.  That's only useful if you want to insert the conversion result into an existing vector, but there's already `cvtdq2pd` to do a packed conversion.  (And they probably didn't have 64bit integers in mind, since AMD64 was still on the drawing board when Intel released SSE2).

Comment: I see it a "bit" more complicated than I've expected.. Thankyou!